# Attempted import error: 'react-transition-group' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactCSSTransitionGroup')

Tags: reactjs

I can't figure out how to set up ReactCSSTransitionGroup. Here are the steps I've attempted:

1. npm install react-transition-group
2. import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group'; (added to the top of my JS file.)

And I get, "Attempted import error: 'react-transition-group' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactCSSTransitionGroup')."

The official documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup) doesn't specify how to fully set this up so I'm a bit lost here.

[image]

Here are the details in the documentation that I'm attempting to follow.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is the most up to date documentation https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the import satement to

`import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';`

or

`import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'`

Comment: I tried those imports but the documentation uses <ReactCSSTransitionGroup> tags in the component examples so it ends ups getting a "not defined" error.

Comment: I added some additional screenshots to provide more context for what I'm attempting.

Comment: ReactTransitionGroup and ReactCSSTransitionGroup have been moved to the react-transition-group package that is maintained by the community. Its 1.x branch is completely API-compatible with the existing addons. Please file bugs and feature requests in the new repository. [link](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition)

Comment: Using CSSTransitionGroup gets rid of the error but doesn't actually do any transitioning